# Single FLINK CEP Pattern exist at a Time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Is it possible to have single pattern for a key at a time. For e.g. I want to check if I get 5 events which matches a where condition within 1 min window and if I get 10 such events with in a min, I should get 2 alerts but i am getting 6 alerts. It is because every event triggers a new pattern. Can we have a single pattern instance at a time for a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have similar problem I had: I do not want the same event to participate in more than one sliding window. I was able to achieve that by using AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipPastLastEvent(). This is available in 1.4. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @sshun. This is what I wanted.